# while installing libpcap-devel on Fedora 21 dependencies error is Coming

Tags: linux, networking, libpcap, fedora-21

While installing libpcap-devel on fedora 21 following error are coming :-

```
**yum install libpcap-devel**
Loaded plugins: langpacks
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package libpcap-devel.x86_64 14:1.6.2-1.fc21 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libpcap = 14:1.6.2-1.fc21 for package: 14:libpcap-devel-1.6.2-1.fc21.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package libpcap.i686 14:1.6.2-1.fc21 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.11) for package: 14:libpcap-1.6.2-1.fc21.i686
--> Running transaction check
---> Package glibc.i686 0:2.20-5.fc21 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: glibc-common = 2.20-5.fc21 for package: glibc-2.20-5.fc21.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libfreebl3.so(NSSRAWHASH_3.12.3) for package: glibc-2.20-5.fc21.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libfreebl3.so for package: glibc-2.20-5.fc21.i686
--> Running transaction check
---> Package glibc.i686 0:2.20-5.fc21 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: glibc-common = 2.20-5.fc21 for package: glibc-2.20-5.fc21.i686
---> Package nss-softokn-freebl.i686 0:3.17.2-1.fc21 will be installed
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: glibc-2.20-5.fc21.i686 (fedora)
       Requires: glibc-common = 2.20-5.fc21
       Installed: glibc-common-2.20-8.fc21.x86_64 (installed)
           glibc-common = 2.20-8.fc21
       Available: glibc-common-2.20-5.fc21.x86_64 (fedora)
           glibc-common = 2.20-5.fc21
  You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
  You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

The kernel i am using-

```
 uname -r
```

4.1.13-100.fc21.x86_64

I cannot erase glibc-common-2.20-8.fc21.x86_64 , since it is with kernel package, can someone help me in this?

Comment: You are installing fedora 21 packages. How did you install fedora 23?

Comment: Sorry it was fedora 21 , i have corrected it...

Comment: Then your [Fedora is EOL](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/End_of_life) and you should update to some supported version.